# Where to get help with Action Script 3 - User groups, etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, actionscript-3

I am developing in rails and have some programming background.

I'm looking for help with Action Script 3, but most of my googling turns up "copy-paste" style answers from designers who don't understand code, and the solutions rarely work.

Where do I go to find Action Script programmers, rather than designers?

To give you an idea of what I'm trying to solve, here's where I'm currently stuck:

- Get the flash file to communicate with rails

  - trying with json, I'm not seeing any requests to the rails server, and I can't tell where the block is. I'm not sure if I'm encountering security issues with the browser trying to stop communication, or if I'm missing something somewhere.
- Get the flash file to redirect the browser
  - I assume this is difficult because it's a security issue, so what's the solution? put javascript on the page, call the flash from javascript, get flash to communicate with javascript and then get javascript to get the browser to redirect?

I think overall it would be good to get some tools that helped debug the communications, requests in and out of flash. I can use wireshark, but I think what I need is something that can tell what flash is trying to get the browser to do, and how the browser is responding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think SO is a good place to get prompt and useful help / guidance. So, I'd ask here.

Other than that, I've been participating in these 2 groups for some time.

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/Flash_tiger/

http://chattyfig.figleaf.com/mailman/listinfo/flashcoders

You'll find some nice and knowledgeable folks over there. Though I'm under the impression that lately these lists are not as active as they used to be a couple of years ago (but maybe that's just me comparing them to SO, which is a very different beast, with a different dynamic).

Answer (score 3):

I mainly use stackowerflow nowadays, but here's two other forums (or a forum and a mailing list):

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/

http://chattyfig.figleaf.com/mailman/listinfo/flashcoders

Comment: ... and for your specific questions, you should look in to URLRequest, URLLoader and navigateToURL.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use

livedocs.adobe.com

(this includes the adobe documentation online as well as tie-ins to forums),

gotoandlearn.com

(this is a great website for purely Flash AS2/AS3 problems),

and here... stackoverflow.com

I also do a lot of google searches, but I seem to come back to these three quite a bit more than the others.